# Map two DB column to one data type using Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

Is it in anyway possible for dapper to map two columns from the database to one .Net data type?
My scenario is that I have monetary values in the database represented as two columns.

```
Cost         Decimal(19,4)  
CostCurrency char(3)
```

And I want it mapped to the custom data type `Money`

```
public partial struct Money
{
   public Money(decimal amount, string currency)
   {
   }
}
```

For example on the insurance entity:

```
public class Insurance
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public Money Cost {get;set;}
}
```

I've been looking at `SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Money>` but it only seems to be able to read/write one column at a time.

Comment: It does not seem to be a DTO representation then, as it should be a dummy flat data container, I would advise to do this in code via a converter dto => transformedObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use the `Split` functionality of dapper:

```
var insurance = (await con.QueryAsync<Insurance, decimal, string, Insurance>(
                   sql,
                   (entity, cost, costCurrency) =>
                   {
                       entity.Cost = new Money(cost, costCurrency);
                       return entity;
                   },
                   splitOn: "Cost, CostCurrency",
                   param: new { Id = id })).Single();
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to find that any mapping of complex properties can be greatly simplified by using private properties to represent the data storage.  Dapper will map to private properties.

```
public class Insurance
{
    #region Data
    private decimal Cost{get{return this.CurrentCost.Amount;} set{this.CurrentCost.Amount = value;}}
    private string Currency{get{return this.CurrentCost.Currency;} set{this.CurrentCost.Currency = value;}}
    #endregion


    public string Id {get;set;}

    //Changed prop name to not confuse it with storage columns
    public Money CurrentCost {get;set;}

    public Insurance(){
        //initialize this so that it won't blow up on mapping
        this.CurrentCost = new Money();
    }
}
```

At first blush this feels like we're marking up our object quite a bit to make it persist and map.  But it's so straight-forward with no magic mapping that it just works. You can unit test all of it too.  And even a project with hundreds of persisting objects this technique will only take up a sliver of time and be totally flexible and manageable throughout the growth of the project.

Comment: Interesting that it maps private properties. Did not know that. But how would we handle the case when `Money` is a (immutable) struct?

Comment: You would have to create the struct when it is called: public Money CurrentCost{get{return new Cost(this.Cost,this.Currency);}}

Comment: ...and I should add, you would make the private properties simple get/sets.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but here is another option:

```
var result = conn.Query(@"select Id = '1', Amount = 12.99, Currency = 'USD' 
                    union all select Id = '2', Amount = 29.58, Currency = 'CAD'")
.Select(row => new Insurance() { Id = row.Id, Cost = new Money(row.Amount, row.Currency) })
.ToList();
```

Comment: I know about this method, but want to avoid it since it is really tedious to having to manually map large entities.